# Tricking my MacOS into thinking it is at my work's network when I am at home

Tags: networking

I am sorry if my title isn't appropriate I am not sure how to better express this. I know it is possible to be done because I have done this in the passed.

Basically I have some documents which I can access when I'm on my work network from certain IPs. I would like to have access to this when I'm at home. I remember I used to do this a long time ago, but I don't remember the name for what I am trying to do or the steps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You were probably using a VPN.

Comment: Hum... I thought so too when looking through stuff. So how do I set up the VPN to make my MacOS think I am on my work network?

Comment: Isn't it that the VPN allows the work network to recognise your mac as a valid machine...

Comment: @theJuls That's a question for your company's IT department.